# React Native AppCenter Push - Notifications when app is in background

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using `React Native Microsoft AppCenter` which leverages `Firebase Cloud Messaging` for an Android app.

- I am receiving the push notifications when the app is **open**,
- When the app is in the **background** the notification appears only in the system tray but no actual `Notification`.

I have to open the tray to see the notification. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you mean for how the UI looks like but it might be the expected behavior. Can you provide screenshots to verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did find the answer in the end. Just in case this is something anybody else trips up on...

You'll need to add the 'sound' key and 'default' value to custom data.

```
"notification_content": {
  "name": "Some Name",
  "title": "Some Title",
  "body": "Some...body",
  "custom_data": { "sound": "default" }
},
"notification_target": {
  "type": "devices_target",
  "devices": ["Some device ID"]
}
```

Comment: hi please help me i need to send notification from react natibe and appcenter push So can you please guide me ?

Comment: What’s the problem?

Comment: I have done the setting as given in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/android, After that when i am sending a notification from app center then i don't get in Emulator. And i have search many things in Google. but i dont get any thing. just provide me some guidance or link which helps me. Thanks in advance